# api retrieve points of interest nearby city

Tags: web-services, api, google-places-api, city, point-of-interest

I am looking for a API/web service for me to retrieve a list of landmarks, points of interest (and their GPS coordinates) near a given city. I tried google places including the query Place Search and type point_of_interest, but the results do not seem satisfactory.

For example, to Paris, I need an answer:
Eiffel Tower, Arc de Triomphe, Champs Elysees, ...

What would you advise me to find such information.

Comment: check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40867833/3623027)

Answer (score 4):

A couple options:

- [Foursquare Venues Platform](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/venues)
- [Factual Places API](http://developer.factual.com/working-with-factual-places/)

Comment: ok, thank you runscope, I'll take a look today at these 2 apis.

Answer (score 2):

Google places has the flag "point_of_interest" but only to show, not for search (see Table 2 in https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/supported_types)

Google Earth on the other hand has what you need. See the icons for Tourist destination, Monument and Historical Place in https://support.google.com/earth/answer/180709?hl=en#what

However I am not sure if there is an API for this data, or if you need to  find a way to extract it from GE.