# retrieve points of interests (attractions/tourist places) of a place/country using google places api

Tags: json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I want to retrieve points of interests of a place/country through google places api say 'points of interests in london'. I want the results to be same as  I google search it like [here][1. I've used something like this

`'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/json?location='+str(lat)+','+str(long)+'&radius=500&type=tourist&rankby=prominence&key=API_KEY')`

where lat,long are respective latitude,longitude of that place/country.

But the resulting json file does not retrieve points of interests of that place rather it just outputs nearby places.

i also tried this

`'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location='+str(lat)+','+str(long)+'&radius=500&type=tourist&&rankby=prominence&key=API_KEY'`

which ended up in same results

is there any option to do it without using radius parameter

please do help me

Comment: `tourist` currently is not a [supported `type`](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types) for requests

Comment: The 500 in the query is 500 meters, which is a pretty short distance for points of interest. But no, as far as I know the prominence ranking is not that great and the resulting list is pretty much random nearby places of the type specified (**tourist** is not supported, you might try point_of_interest but you are still unlikely to get actual tourist attractions).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this google places API url. You will get the point of interest/Attraction/Tourists places in (For Eg:) **New York City**. You have to use the **CITY NAME** with the keyword **Point Of Interest**

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=new+york+city+point+of+interest&language=en&key=API_KEY
```

These API results are same as the results of the below google search results.

https://www.google.com/search?sclient=psy-ab&site=&source=hp&btnG=Search&q=New+York+point+of+interest

Comment: These two don't return the same results at all. The Google seach does show a list of tourist attractions in relative popularity, but the api textsearch returns mostly a list of random local travel realted businesses. Here are the top five results I get for each. From www.google.com/search.... Central Park, Statue of Liberty, Empire State Building, High Line, Times Square. From maps.googleapis.com/maps/api... CitySights NY, Federal Hall, Top of The Rock, The New York Pass, City Sightseeing New York.

Answer (score 2):

I worked on a project that made extensive use of this functionality. In the end, the best way to get attractions in a city was to use a query like:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=your-query-here&types=establishment&location=37.76999,-122.44696&radius=500&key=YOUR_API_KEY

If you want points of interest that aren't businesses, remove the `types=establishment` arg.

Answer (score 1):

Try this google place API url. 
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=point+of+interest+in+cityName&key=API_KEY

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may be looking for an API that surfaces Google Search results, and there is one: Google Custom Search https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/overview

You could use Nearby or Radar search, if you'd be looking for more specific, supported types: https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types#table1

Comment: And it looks like you might want to start using it (just give it a try :)

Answer (score 0):

Please tied to use google API

1. **Step 1 :**
   **Create Google API key  [Get API Key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key)**
2. **Step 2: Add Places API**
3. **Step 3: Implement**

`$url= "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=dubai+point+of+interest&language=en&radius=2000&key=API_KEY";`

```
$json=file_get_contents($url);

$obj = json_decode($json);

print_r($obj);
```