# Get all tourist locations using google places api

Tags: android, json, google-places-api

I need to get all the points of interest ( tourist locations ) around a person's location rank by distance. I am using this is URL to do

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=37.4219983,-122.084&rankby=distance&type=point_of_interest&key=

but the problem is that it is not returning any tourist location, instead, it is showing me all the places a person can visit including cafe, restaurants, clubs etc.

I only want tourist locations like for example, in case of Los Angeles, it should be Griffith Observatory, Universal Studios, Santa Monica Pier etc.

I did try textsearch api but it doesnt give me any proper result.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=new+york+city+point+of+interest&language=en&key=

The above URL only gives around 20 results and I have to manually enter the name of the city which I don't want to do that. I want to search points of interest around a person's current location ranked by distance.

I have looked into [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37874018/retrieve-points-of-interests-attractions-tourist-places-of-a-place-country-usi) but it doesn't help.

Comment: were you able to solve this ?

Comment: @rohansethi not completely but searching something like "Los Angeles points of interest" gives the somewhat decent result.  For accurate result you will look into some other api which i am not able to find any or implement it on your own.

Comment: I guess google's business API allows to retrieve #ratings and  #reviews . But the public API prohibits.

Answer (score 1):

Here we can use the **point of interest** option for this......

"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query='PLACE_NAME'+point+of+interest&language=en&key=Your_API_KEY"

Answer (score 0):

As far as i am aware you cant. I would suggest using Museums, Stadiums and city_hall ect. Things that would be places of attractions and only a relatively small amount of  items

Comment: are there any other api which can do my job?